# Cassandra cql equivalent of over() from sql

Tags: database, cassandra, cql

Is there a cql equivalent of the sql over() window function? I need to use a window function to group data in my cassandra table and I can't find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra has very limited support for aggregation functions. This specific function doesn't exist in the CQL. If you need to perform this operation over the data in Cassandra, then you can use [Spark SQL Window functions](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html) on the data fetched via [Spark Cassandra Connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md).